# Stop landscape orientation from flipping vertically

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin, monogame

I have the following metadata for my Activity:

```
    , MainLauncher = true
    , Icon = "@drawable/icon"
    , Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash"
    , AlwaysRetainTaskState = true
    , LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask
    , ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape
    , ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.Keyboard | ConfigChanges.KeyboardHidden)]
```

According to the documentation [activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html), it says SensorLandscape should flip based on sensor, and Landscape should just remain in landscape without flipping.  However, whenever I rotate the screen 180 degrees, it flips.  How do I keep it in a single landscape?

Comment: Have you tried `nosensor`?

Comment: No sensor seems to have no effect.

Comment: Yes it should remain in Landscape if android:screenOrientation="landscape", but check in code if you are changing the Activity orientation

Comment: Yes, you're correct.  Monogame was controlling the orientation.